# Extra content at the end of the document XML PHP RSS

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to create a RSS feed. This is the PHP code for the feed in question below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?php

include_once 'authorization.php';
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

    $demo_id = "1";
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM demo_files WHERE demo_id = ?");

  $stmt->bind_param('i', $demo_id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $demo_title=$row['demo_title'];
        $demo_content=$row['demo_content'];

        echo '<rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
        <title>Liorall</title>
        <link><a href="https://www.example.com">Youtube Tutorial demo</a></link>
        <language>en-us</language>

          <item>
            <title>'.$post_title.'</title>
            <description>'.$post_content.'</description>
          </item>

        </channel>
        </rss>';
    }
    ?>
```

Am getting this error **Extra content at the end of the document**
Please how can i fix it.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're initialising `$demo_title` and `$demo_content` at the top of your loop, but emitting `$post_title` and `$post_content` later.

That will generate an `undefined variable` warning from PHP that will appear in your output stream and your RSS reader is likely to complain about that.

I changed that on my test system and the output now appears well-formed, but it fails the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/) with some other issues you should address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... i followed your step but still getting the error. can you help me rewrite d output?

Comment: am thinking it has to do with my select query. me removing the queries and replacing the variables with actual words work

Comment: Nevermind. i followed the tutorial on https://www.webslesson.info/2019/03/creating-valid-rss-feed-in-php.html?m=1 it works